# azure functions : Getting objectid from user email in azure AD

Tags: function, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, objectid

We want get the objectid of users from their user principal name(emailids) and also we want the functions to be called in an automated fashion may be from a web hook

Kindly let us know how to do the same

Comment: Could you provide more details about the second part of the question?Or what have you test so far?

Comment: We want to trigger the azure function from a webhook may be from application like jira . The function will get the emailids as input and we need to get the objectid from the emails so that we can assign it one of the other API

Comment: You want to get the emailids as input and objectid as output? Use C# or JS, etc?

Comment: yes i know that. We cannot use graph bindings for azure functions as it does not work  locally with vscode. There is a blog talking about how to do it from azure portal https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/06/27/using-microsoft-graph-in-an-azure-function/. This needs AAD integration to sign in to azure function. If we want to integrate function from a different system we cannot use that also.Can anybody from azure function team help on this .